# Can't encode HTML special characters in Sublime Text 2

Tags: encoding, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've always been able to encode html special characters in Sublime Text 2 with the keyboard shortcut [Shift]+[Cmd]+[p] then *HTML: Encode special characters*. For some unknown reason, the latter is no longer available when I type the keyboard shortcut. Is there a particular package that needs to be installed in order for the encoding to be applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use more functional plugin [SublimeStringEncode](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeStringEncode).

1. Install it using Package Control, type "StringEncode".
2. <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then "HTML entitize"

---

In addition you will have some other useful commands:

- `html_deentitize`: Converts HTML entities to a character
- `url_encode`: Uses urllib.quote to escape special URL characters
- `url_decode`: Uses urllib.unquote to convert escaped URL characters
- `json_escape`: Escapes a string and surrounds it in quotes, according to the JSON encoding.
- `json_unescape`: Unescapes a string (include the quotes!) according to JSON encoding.
- `base64_encode`: Uses base64 to encode into base64
- `base64_decode`: Uses base64 to decode from base64
- `md5_encode`: Uses sha package to create md5 hash
- `sha256_encode`: Uses sha package to create sha256 hash
- `sha512_encode`: Uses sha package to create sha512 hash
- `escape_regex`: Escapes regex meta characters
- `escape_like`: Escapes SQL-LIKE meta characters
- `safe_html_entitize`: Converts characters to their HTML entity, but preserves HTML reserved characters
- `safe_html_deentitize`: Converts HTML entities to a character, but preserves HTML reserved characters
- `xml_entitize`: Converts characters to their XML entity
- `xml_deentitize`: Converts XML entities to a character

Comment: @MichelWilliams I see you have no "vote up" privillege, but you still can accept the answer.

Comment: I can´t install